# Effective way how to handle application settings in PL/pgSQL functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Consider following situation: I have PL/pgSQL function which checks, If given auditor has some prerequisites for QS Auditor function. Thresholds of this prerequisites are defined in separate table `quasar_settings`. Every time, If is the function called, is executed SELECT which retrieves these prerequisites. This is quite inefficient, because this SELECT is called for every row. This quasar_settings table contains only one row. Is there any other more effective solution (global variable, caching, etc)?

*Table quasar_settings has only one row.*
*Using PostgreSQL 9.3*

**PL/pgSQL function**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION qs_auditor_training_auditing(auditor quasar_auditor) RETURNS boolean AS $$
DECLARE
    settings quasar_settings%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT s INTO settings
    FROM quasar_settings s LIMIT 1;
    RETURN auditor.nb1023_procedures_hours >= settings.qs_auditor_nb1023_procedures AND
           -- MD Training
           auditor.mdd_hours +  auditor.ivd_hours >= settings.qs_auditor_md_training AND
            -- ISO 9001 Trainig
           (
            auditor.is_aproved_for_iso13485 OR
            (auditor.is_aproved_for_iso9001 AND auditor.iso13485_hours >= settings.qs_auditor_iso13485_training) OR
            (auditor.iso13485_hours + auditor.iso9001_hours >= settings.qs_auditor_class_room_training)
           );
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**Example of usage**:

```
SELECT auditor.id, qs_auditor_training_auditing(auditor) FROM quasar_auditor auditor;
```

Comment: Your tags don't make sense. PL/SQL is the procedural language used in Oracle RDBMS, whereas the procedural language used in PostgreSQL is called PL/pgSQL. Please make up your mind and fix the tags :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a cross join to the settings table in instead of calling the function at every row

```
select
    a.id,
    a.nb1023_procedures_hours >= s.qs_auditor_nb1023_procedures and
    -- md training
    a.mdd_hours + a.ivd_hours >= s.qs_auditor_md_training and
     -- iso 9001 trainig
    (
        a.is_aproved_for_iso13485 or
        (
            a.is_aproved_for_iso9001 and
            a.iso13485_hours >= s.qs_auditor_iso13485_training
        ) or
        (a.iso13485_hours + a.iso9001_hours >= s.qs_auditor_class_room_training)
    )
from
    quasar_auditor a
    cross join
    quasar_settings s
```